# Finding words ending in letters "it" ... while negating all other words?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm using a dictionary file. I just only need words to end in "it". I'm using a counter to count double consonants when ending in "ed" of those words. The code I'm supposed to receive back is (last 3 lines):

```
wait waited
worrit worrited
simple= 83    double= 45"
```

From what I have, all I need to do is get rid of all other words that don't end in "it" and I'm having trouble coming up with a solution. The word.endswith is just reprinting some of the words.

```
words=[line.rstrip() for line in open('')]
wordset=set(words) 
count=0 
countt=0 
for word in words:
    if word[-1] != 't': continue
    if word+'i' in wordset: continue
    simple = word + 'ed'
    double = word + 'ted'
    if simple in wordset:
         print(word,simple) 
         count+=1
    elif double in wordset:
        print(word,double,'*')
        countt+=1
print('simple=',count,'   double=',countt)
```

Comment: do you want to count a "tt" word (`"tt" in word`) if it doesn't end with "it" (`word.endswith("it")`)?

Comment: I just only need words to end in "it". I'm using a counter to count double consonants when ending in "ed" of those words.

Comment: You're only checking for _ending in t_. Wouldn't `if word[-2:] != 'it': continue` be more fitting? What is `if word+'i' in wordset: continue` supposed to accomplish?

Comment: @TomBombadil: I find `word.endswith("it")` more readable than `word[-2:] == 'it'`

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: I agree, I was just wondering why he just checked for _t_ and not _it_.

Comment: I was searching for words ending in "t" so that I could find the double consonants when adding in "ed"

Comment: Thanks! The line "if word[-2:] != 'it': continue " worked. I tried that previously but forgot the colon

Answer (score 1):

```
words = "wait waited worrit worrited simple"
word = words.split()
for w in word:
    if w.endswith('it'):
        print(w)
    else:
        pass
```

> Here I have split the string by space and hence got a list.
>   There after I checked whether the list
>   elements endswith 'it' or not

Comment: Good answers *explain* as well as provide code. Consider updating your answer to include an explanation about how this code works and why it is the best option.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Ajean